# Export to HTML5 FWebSocketsModule not working

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm exporting UE4 Project (version 4.23) to HTML5 that has `WebSockets` module enabled in `.Build.cs`:

`PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "WebSockets" });`

It works fine when I play in Editor, but when I call `FWebSocketsModule::Get().CreateWebSocket(url, protocol)` on exported project, this method is not found.

Did check `FWebSocketsModule.cpp` and function is declared:

```
#if WITH_WEBSOCKETS
TSharedRef<IWebSocket> FWebSocketsModule::CreateWebSocket(....
....
#endif
```

So, `WITH_WEBSOCKETS` is set to `0` when exporting/running to html

I did declare this macro on my class and set to 1, but it got stuck at `Loading engine...` in browser

Did I miss any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to call websockets from HTML by including emscripten websockets

in `<Project>.Build.cs` constructor:

```
if (Target.Platform == UnrealTargetPlatform.HTML5)
    {
        string libwebs = "<Engine instal dir>/UE_4.23/Engine/Extras/ThirdPartyNotUE/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.31/src/library_websocket.js";
        PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(libwebs);
    }
```

In my GameInstance.h class (or whenever you want to register websockets):

```
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
#include <emscripten/html5.h>
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/websocket.h>
#endif
```

In .cpp class:

```
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
static EMSCRIPTEN_WEBSOCKET_T socket;

static  EM_BOOL onopen(int eventType, const EmscriptenWebSocketOpenEvent* websocketEvent, void* userData) {
    //code logic ...
    return EM_TRUE;
}
static  EM_BOOL  onerror(int eventType, const EmscriptenWebSocketErrorEvent* websocketEvent, void* userData) {
    //code logic ...
    return EM_TRUE;
}
static  EM_BOOL  onclose(int eventType, const EmscriptenWebSocketCloseEvent* websocketEvent, void* userData) {
    //code logic ...
    return EM_TRUE;
}
static  EM_BOOL onmessage(int eventType, const EmscriptenWebSocketMessageEvent* websocketEvent, void* userData) {
    Yourclass* instance = reinterpret_cast<YourClass*>(userData);
    //code logic ...
    instance->YourNonStaticFunc(..);
    return EM_TRUE;
}
#endif
```

In your .cpp Init/Method:

```
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
if (!emscripten_websocket_is_supported()) {
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("\nemscripten_websocket not supoported :/\n"));
    return;
}

EmscriptenWebSocketCreateAttributes ws_attrs = { TCHAR_TO_ANSI("ws://ip_address:port", NULL, EM_TRUE };

socket = emscripten_websocket_new(&ws_attrs);
emscripten_websocket_set_onopen_callback(socket, this, onopen);
emscripten_websocket_set_onerror_callback(socket, this, onerror);
emscripten_websocket_set_onclose_callback(socket, this, onclose);
emscripten_websocket_set_onmessage_callback(socket, this, onmessage);
#endif
```

For more about emscripten functions, you can check at: `<Your engine install dir>/UE_4.23/Engine/Extras/ThirdPartyNotUE/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.31/system/include/emscripten/[websocket.h, emscripten.h, html5.h]`